# DBAN SSD and then re-install Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, installation, oem

I'm about to DBAN (Dariks boot and Nuke) a 30GB SSD, and then re-install Windows-7 to the disk.  Question 1, is there any special setting to DBAN for SSDs (only single pass overwrite is needed I suppose)? Question 2, is there any issue in the re-install process using a Windows 7 Home Premium OEM disk to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have to re-align your partition to match SSD layout. Google for it, don't know the latest docs.
2. Get a list of currently installed drivers first. At least for your networking card.